# Meta Database for a multi-tenant multi-shard environment

Tags: sharding

I’ve spent quite a bit of time researching sharding of a multi-tenant database (for a SAAS application).  I wasn’t able to find much information on handling the Meta Database, containing connections and common data for the tenant databases. A simplified model of what I'm working on would look like this: several servers, 2 or more shards with identical structure on each server, each shard containing a few databases with data for a subset of the tenants (example: Server 1; shards 1; tenants 1- 500; databases A, B, C with data for tenant 1-500).

I’ve attached a simplified model for a single server.[image]

My question is what approach should I use for the Meta Database once the shards are distributed on more than 1 server? It is straight forward(and my proof of concept worked well) having 1 Meta Database connecting the shards on only 1 server(which will be the case in the beginning), but the implementation would be different for multiple servers with multiple shards each, since the Meta Database would need to contain the connection to each tenant.

This is a relatively new territory for me so your thoughts and any guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Vilyana

Comment: What RDBMS are you planning to use, and why shard? RDBMSes are highly scalable without the need for sharding.

Comment: Phil, I'm using SQL Server...and, yes, I'm aware of the pros and cons of Sharding. I think in the case above the solution could be as 'simple' as having a copy of the same Meta DB on each server which would enable the application to obtain the correct connection (and common data) for each tenant, regardless of the location. Have you dealt with anything similar in the past?